# Showing a View on a button click in rhoMobile

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I have created a simple project in rhomobile.
My home screen shows a text box and a button.

here is the code for that in `index.erb`

```
<div data-role="content">
<br /><br />
 Email Address : <input type="text" name="Email" /><br />
  <form method="POST" action="<%= url_for(:action =>:show_VibLoc) %>">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Now I have created a new file `VibLoc.erb` in settings folder which is under app folder.

in `VibLoc.erb` i am showing just two buttons.

In the `controller.rb` file under settings folder i have created a function `show_VibLoc`

in This function it renders the `VibLoc.erb` file

here is the code:

```
def show_VibLoc
render :action => :VibLoc
end
```

The code compiles successfully but when i click on that button i cant see my `VibLoc` view.

what i am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolved it by my self.

Instead of writing this code in `index.erb`

```
<div data-role="content">
<br /><br />
Email Address : <input type="text" name="Email" /><br />
<form method="POST" action="<%= url_for(:action =>:show_VibLoc) %>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

replace it with this one

```
<div data-role="content">
<br /><br />
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  Email Address : <input type="text" name="Email" /><br />
  </div>
  <form method="POST" action="<%= url_for(:controller => :Settings, :action =>:show_VibLoc) %>">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Thanks for looking at this question :)

Answer (score 3):

Had faced the same issue once, the approach i found out was:

1. to create a .js file in the public/js folder in the project with a function to call a method from the controller :

   ```
   function ajaxBridge(method,funcName,onSuccess)
   {
   $.ajax({
       type: method,
       url: funcName,
       async: true,
       error: function(xhr){alert("Custom Uncaught AjaxBridge Error 11 :" + "<br/>" + xhr.responseText);},
       success: onSuccess
       });
   }
   ```
2. on you .erb file or view you can have :

   ```
   <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="doValidation()"/>
   ```
3. create a script on the same page to call our ajax method, i am also sending login information to the method :

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function doValidation(){
       var login = $('input#login').val();
       var password = $('input#password').val();
       ajaxBridge("POST","<%= url_for :controller => :Survey, :action => :do_login %>"+"?login="+login +"&password="+password,function(){});
     }
   </script>
   ```

Note: Do include
      `<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/AjaxConnector.js"></script>`
to specify the source for the ajax.

hope i helped.